# Cannot find symbol error on compile.

Tags: java

I am doing a project for class and was cleaning up my indentation etc and have done something to my code. I cannot see the forest for the trees and could use some help. I am getting a cannot find symbol error when I compile. Here is the code.

```
public class TrafficLights extends JFrame implements ItemListener
{
    private JRadioButton jrbRed;
    private JRadioButton jrbYellow;
    private JRadioButton jrbGreen;
    private ButtonGroup btg = new ButtonGroup();

    private TrafficLights.Light light = new TrafficLights.Light();
                  //     ^ error 1 is here               ^ error 2 is here       

public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    TrafficLights frame = new TrafficLights();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
    frame.setSize(200, 200);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    }

public TrafficLights()
    {
    setTitle("Traffic Light Signal");

    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
    p1.setLayout(new FlowLayout(1));
    p1.add(this.light);

    JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
    p2.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    p2.add(this.jrbRed = new JRadioButton("Red"));
    p2.add(this.jrbYellow = new JRadioButton("Yellow"));
    p2.add(this.jrbGreen = new JRadioButton("Green"));

    this.jrbRed.setMnemonic('R');
    this.jrbYellow.setMnemonic('Y');
    this.jrbGreen.setMnemonic('G');

    this.btg.add(this.jrbRed);
    this.btg.add(this.jrbYellow);
    this.btg.add(this.jrbGreen);

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(p1, "Center");
    add(p2, "South");

    this.jrbRed.addItemListener(this);
    this.jrbYellow.addItemListener(this);
    this.jrbGreen.addItemListener(this);

    this.jrbGreen.setSelected(true);
    this.light.turnOnGreen();
    }

public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
    {
        if (this.jrbRed.isSelected())
            {
            this.light.turnOnRed();
            }

        if (this.jrbYellow.isSelected())
            {
            this.light.turnOnYellow();
            }

        if (this.jrbGreen.isSelected())
            {
            this.light.turnOnGreen();
            }

class Light extends JPanel
    {
    private boolean red;
    private boolean yellow;
    private boolean green;

public Light()
{ }

public void turnOnRed()
{
    this.red = true;
    this.yellow = false;
    this.green = false;
    repaint();
}

public void turnOnYellow()
{
    this.red = false;
    this.yellow = true;
    this.green = false;
    repaint();
}

public void turnOnGreen()
{
    this.red = false;
    this.yellow = false;
    this.green = true;
    repaint();
}

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);

    if (this.red)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillOval(10, 10, 20, 20);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawOval(10, 35, 20, 20);
            g.drawOval(10, 60, 20, 20);
            g.drawRect(5, 5, 30, 80);
        }

    else if (this.yellow)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.yellow);
            g.fillOval(10, 35, 20, 20);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawRect(5, 5, 30, 80);
            g.drawOval(10, 10, 20, 20);
            g.drawOval(10, 60, 20, 20);
        }

    else if (this.green)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.fillOval(10, 60, 20, 20);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawRect(5, 5, 30, 80);
            g.drawOval(10, 10, 20, 20);
            g.drawOval(10, 35, 20, 20);
        }

else
    {
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawRect(5, 5, 30, 80);
        g.drawOval(10, 10, 20, 20);
        g.drawOval(10, 35, 20, 20);
        g.drawOval(10, 60, 20, 20);
    }
}

public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
        return new Dimension(100, 100);
    }
}
}
}
```

Comment: What symbol isn't found?

Comment: Why `TrafficLights.Light`? Just use `Light`.

Comment: Your Light isn't a static class..just use Light

Comment: It looks like you are defining class `Light` inside another class... Did you mean to do that?

Answer (score 2):

This is the problem - I've indented the code to make it clearer...

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
{
    if (this.jrbRed.isSelected())
    {
        this.light.turnOnRed();
    }

    if (this.jrbYellow.isSelected())
    {
        this.light.turnOnYellow();
    }

    if (this.jrbGreen.isSelected())
    {
        this.light.turnOnGreen();
    }

    class Light extends JPanel
    {
        private boolean red;
        private boolean yellow;
        private boolean green;
       ...
```

You're currently declaring the `Light` class *within* the `itemStateChanged` method. I don't think you meant to do that.

Additionally, I would question whether you really need `Light` to be an inner or nested class itself. I would suggest making it a top-level class - at least to start with. It'll be easier to navigate that way, apart from anything else.

I'd also strongly suggest trying to keep on top of your indentation at all times. If the rest of your code is already nicely indented, it's easier to see when something goes wrong. IDEs such as Eclipse are able to indent all your code for you at the touch of a button - I would advise you to use that feature heavily.

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow? Do I need to make light an outer class by moving it after the main?

Comment: @KevinSchultz: You'd probably make it an outer class by moving it to a different file altogether. But at the very least you need to move it outside your `itemStateChanged` method.